# How do I make a working if statement that repeats on if false in Python?

Tags: python, if-statement

```
name = input("What is your name?\n")

menu = "Black Coffee", "Espresso", "Latte", "Cappucino","Frappuccino"

while True:
   order = input(name + ", what would you like from our menu today? Here is what we are serving.\n")
   if order == "Black Coffee":
       print("Thank you.")
   elif order == "Espresso":
        print("Thank you.")
   elif order == "Latte":
        print("Thank you.")
   elif order == "Cappucino":
        print("Thank you.")
   elif order == "Frappucino":
        print("Thank you.")
   else:
       print("play again.. etc...")

quantity = input("How many " + order + "s would you like?\n")

total = price * int(quantity)

total_time = int(quantity) * time

print("Thank you. Your total is: $" + str(total))

print("Sounds good " + name + ", we will have your " + quantity + " "+ order + " ready for you in " + str(total_time) + " min.")
```

I am a guy who is a beginner in Python. I have a problem with my code that when I enter for example "Latte" It will say "Thank you." and it jumps back and says "name + , what would you like from our menu today? Here is what we are serving.". I do not want that to happen, instead I want it to say the line under it (How many " + order + "s would you like?). Also, when I add the variable "menu" to my "order" variable (in the string) it says "can only concatenate str (not "tuple") to str"
I would really appreciate your help.

Comment: You need to put a `break` inside the `while True` loop when you want the loop to stop.

Comment: do you understand why it jumps back - do you understand what `while True` does?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [the `break` keyword](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#break-and-continue-statements-and-else-clauses-on-loops) to break out of the while loop:

```
while True:
   order = input(name + ", what would you like from our menu today? Here is what we are serving.\n")
   if order in menu:
       print("Thank you.")
       break
   else:
       print("play again.. etc...")
```

Comment: converting the menu to a set will further improve the code.

Comment: @Mr.Slicer You're most welcome. If my answer solves your problem, consider marking it "accepted" by clicking the checkmark on the left :)

Comment: I will, but I have to wait 5 min.